# Conditions in Spark window function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a dataframe like

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  q|  w|  e|  r|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  1| 20|  y|
|  a|  2| 22|  z|
|  b|  3| 10|  y|
|  b|  4| 12|  y|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I want to mark the rows with the minimum `e` and `r = z` . If there are no rows which have `r = z`, I want the row with the minimum `e`, even if `r = y`.
Essentially, something like

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  q|  w|  e|  r|  t|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  1| 20|  y|  0|
|  a|  2| 22|  z|  1|
|  b|  3| 10|  y|  1|
|  b|  4| 12|  y|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I can do it using a number of joins, but that would be too expensive.
So I was looking for a window-based solution.

Comment: What would be the role of the columns `q` and `w`?

Comment: @werner - those would be required for later unrelated steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the minimum per group once for rows with `r = z` and then for all rows within a group. The first non-null value can then be compared to `e`:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = ...

w = Window.partitionBy("q")
#When ordering is not defined, an unbounded window frame is used by default.

df.withColumn("min_e_with_r_eq_z", F.expr("min(case when r='z' then e else null end)").over(w)) \
    .withColumn("min_e_overall", F.min("e").over(w)) \
    .withColumn("t", F.coalesce("min_e_with_r_eq_z","min_e_overall") == F.col("e")) \
    .orderBy("w") \
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+-----------------+-------------+-----+
|  q|  w|  e|  r|min_e_with_r_eq_z|min_e_overall|    t|
+---+---+---+---+-----------------+-------------+-----+
|  a|  1| 20|  y|               22|           20|false|
|  a|  2| 22|  z|               22|           20| true|
|  b|  3| 10|  y|             null|           10| true|
|  b|  4| 12|  y|             null|           10|false|
+---+---+---+---+-----------------+-------------+-----+
```

*Note*: I assume that `q` is the grouping column for the window.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the spark-scala version of @werner 's accepted answer

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("q")

df.withColumn("min_e_with_r_eq_z", min(when($"r" === "z", $"e").otherwise(null)).over(w))
  .withColumn("min_e_overall", min("e").over(w))
  .withColumn("t", coalesce($"min_e_with_r_eq_z", $"min_e_overall") === $"e")
  .orderBy("w")
  .show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign row numbers based on whether `r = z` and the value of column `e`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    't', 
     F.when(
        F.row_number().over(
            Window.partitionBy('q')
                  .orderBy((F.col('r') == 'z').desc(), 'e')
        ) == 1, 
        1
    ).otherwise(0)
)

df2.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  q|  w|  e|  r|  t|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  2| 22|  z|  1|
|  a|  1| 20|  y|  0|
|  b|  3| 10|  y|  1|
|  b|  4| 12|  y|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Nice idea using the row numbers (+1). But shouldn't you use an unbounded window?

Comment: I just care about the first row in each group, so I suppose the window boundary should be irrelevant

Comment: @mck row_number is a nice touch if only the first row is required.